# Como fazer um select com base em dados de outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho que fazer a seguinte adaptação em uma query:

Tabela `app_usuários`: `id, nome, sobrenome, hash, sexo, interesse, latitude e longitude`.

Tabela `app_likes`: `id, user_a_id, user_b_id`

Resumidamente, tenho um query que pega os usuários com base no sexo e interesse em um raio de 25 quilômetros.

O que eu preciso fazer: Tenho que fazer a query não pegar usuários que eu já dei like acessando a tabela `app_likes`, sei que tenho de fazer isso com `inner join`, mas como? Considerem que `user_a_id` seria o id de quem deu like.

Minha query:

```
$teste  = $app->database->query("SELECT user_id, user_firstname, latitude, longitude,
(6371 * acos(
 cos( radians(".$app->session->user_data[0]['latitude'].") )
 * cos( radians( latitude ) )
 * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(".$app->session->user_data[0]['longitude'].") )
 + sin( radians(".$app->session->user_data[0]['latitude'].") )
 * sin( radians( latitude ) ) 
 )
) AS distancia
FROM app_users ".$query."
HAVING distancia < 25
ORDER BY distancia ASC
LIMIT 4;", $array);
```

De onde vem as variáveis $query e $array:

```
if($app->session->user_data[0]['user_interest'] == "m" || $app->session->user_data[0]['user_interest'] == "f"){
  $query = "WHERE user_gender = :ug AND (user_interest = :uin OR user_interest = :reserved) not in (".$app->session->user_data[0]['user_id'].")";
  $array = array("ug"=>$app->session->user_data[0]['user_interest'], "uin"=>$app->session->user_data[0]['user_gender'],"reserved"=>"fm");
} else if($app->session->user_data[0]['user_interest'] == "fm"){
  $query = "WHERE user_interest = :uin OR user_interest = :reserved not in (".$app->session->user_data[0]['user_id'].")";
  $array = array("uin"=>$app->session->user_data[0]['user_gender'],"reserved"=>"fm");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para não apanhar os utilizadores que já deram *like* teria que fazer um `LEFT JOIN` com a tabela `app_likes`:

```
$teste  = $app->database->query("   SELECT      user_id
                                            ,   user_firstname
                                            ,   latitude
                                            ,   longitude
                                            ,   (6371 * acos(       cos(radians(".$app->session->user_data[0]['latitude'].")) 
                                                                *   cos(radians(latitude)) 
                                                                *   cos(radians(longitude) - radians(".$app->session->user_data[0]['longitude'].")) 
                                                                +   sin(radians(".$app->session->user_data[0]['latitude'].")) 
                                                                *   sin(radians(latitude)) 
                                                            )
                                                ) AS distancia
                                    FROM        app_users au
                                    LEFT JOIN   app_likes al ON al.user_b_id = au.id 
                                                            AND al.user_a_id = ".$app->session->user_data[0]['user_id']."
                                    WHERE       al.id IS NULL
                                            AND ".$query."
                                    HAVING      distancia < 25
                                    ORDER BY    distancia ASC
                                    LIMIT 4;", $array);
```

Terá que remover o `WHERE` da sua variável `$query` e colocar uns parêntesis onde utiliza o `OR`, caso contrário vai misturar os resultados.

**Nota**: não coloquei plicas na condição `AND al.user_a_id = ".$app->session->user_data[0]['user_id']."` porque não sei de que tipo de dados é, mas se for `string` ou um tipo `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` deverá colocar.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta e coloquei de onde vem as variaveis $query e $array

Comment: Resposta editada para considerar o conteúdo da variável `$query`.

Comment: João, obrigado por ajuda. Mas não acho que você não entendeu direito. Seria assim, se user_b_id for igual ao id do registro que veio da consulta, o mesmo não seria incluído no resultado.

Comment: Referiu que o campo `user_a_id` era o campo que deveria ligar à tabela `app_likes`, e se assim for, ligando as duas tabelas com o `LEFT JOIN` e dizendo que não queremos os registos dos utilizadores que já deram _like_ (têm um registo na tabela `app_likes`), então penso ser o que estava a pedir, certo?

Comment: Vamos lá. Vou tentar explicar utilizando algorítimo. [Selecione 4 usuários em um raio de 25 quilômetros, verifique também se foi retornado algum usuário em que eu já dei like utilizando a tabela app_likes, considerando que user_a_id é o meu id e user_b_id é o id dos outros usuários, caso seja encontrado não retorne esses resultados]

Comment: Simplesmente quero que a query me retorne usuários com os requisitos definidos no WHERE e que a query exclua usuários que eu já dei like, utilizando a tabela app_like. Considerando que user_a_id é o meu id e user_b_id é o id do usuário em quem eu dei like.

Comment: Ok, está difícil. O que é que está a ser retornado na _query_ inicial?

Comment: A variavel $query manda as preferências do usuário para a consulta.

Comment: Se o usuário for bissexual, manda selecionar homens e mulheres que estejam interessado no gênero dele. Se o usuário for hétero, seleciona o sexo oposto que esteja interessado no gênero dele. Assim funciona a variável $query. Já a variável $array contem os dados dessas preferências.

Comment: Considere que $app->session->user_data[0] contém os dados do usuário que está logado

Comment: Acho que já percebi o cenário! Editei a resposta para no `JOIN` apanhar os resultados em que o utilizador representado pelo `user_b_id` tenha _likes_ e ao mesmo tempo que esses _likes_ venham do utilizador que está logado, depois na cláusula `WHERE` dizemos que todos esses resultados devem ser removidos da consulta.

Comment: Cara, você é incrível! Funcionou perfeitamente.